# Assembly language coding help required

Tags: assembly

Can someone improve on this code (MC9S08JM60):

```
ldhx  #0xDFC4;  // Vector location
ldhx  ,x        // Fetch vector contents
jsr   ,x        // Execute interrupt function
```

What I want to do is to jump at the location 0xABCD, where, *0xAB* lies in **0xDFC4** and *0xCD* lies in **0xDFC5**.

So, the above code doesn't seem to jump to **ABCD** location.

Comment: What's the endianness of this processor? Does `ldhx  #0xABCD; jsr ,x` do what you need?

Comment: It's an 8-bit microcontroller, so that question is moot, no?

Comment: Are you able to single-step and view the contents of H:X before the `jsr` instruction?  Does it match the value at 0xDFC4?  Do you know where it *is* jumping?

Comment: @Rooke: No, it's not a moot point.  8-bit microcontrollers typically can address more than 256 bytes of RAM.  The `ldhx` instruction loads 16 bits, so endianness *does* matter.

Comment: @Rookie: I have no idea about this particular controller or its instuction set. OP assummed big endianness, so I've asked him to test something that does not depend on it.

Answer (score 1):

The HCS08 [Reference Manual](http://www.freescale.com/files/microcontrollers/doc/ref_manual/HCS08RMV1.pdf) is handy in a situation like this:

The immediate mode of the instruction LDHX loads in the byte at address 0xDFC4 into the "H" register, and the byte at address 0xDFC5 into the "X" register.

I think your second instruction is ok.

But your third instruction, JumptoSubRoutine (JSR) does an offset jump, I think. Try JMP ,x

Note also, JSR does a push of the current (return) address to the stack, effectively incrementing the stack pointer by two.